# python logging shows no sys.stdout when from different thread

Tags: python, multithreading, logging, telegram-bot

i now have a strange problem with logging in my multithreaded python application. Whenever i debug the application, i properly see the logging output in the stdout, such as

```
2016-11-05 21:51:36,851 (connectionpool.py:735 MainThread) INFO -     requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool: "Starting new HTTPS connection (1): api.telegram.org"
2016-11-05 21:51:41,920 (converter.py:16 WorkerThread1) DEBUG - converter: "resizing file test/test_input/"
2016-11-05 21:51:50,199 (bot.py:221 WorkerThread1) ERROR - __main__: "MoviePy error: failed to read the duration of file test/test_input/.
```

However, when i run the code without debug, all the logs from the `WorkingThread1` disappear, leaving only the `MainThread` ones. The code is unchanged and the error remains. I guess it has something to do with multithreading. The `WorkerThread1` is started from the `pyTelegramBotAPI` framework. I have my logs output to the `sys.stdout`:

```
formatter = logging.Formatter(
    '%(asctime)s (%(filename)s:%(lineno)d %(threadName)s) %(levelname)s - %(name)s: "%(message)s"')
stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
root = logging.getLogger()
root.setLevel(logging.NOTSET)
root.addHandler(stream_handler)
```

Any ideas?

**Update**: it has 100% to do with multithreading, because when i tell the framework to only use one thread, the logging messages appear. `pyTelegramBotAPI` uses `WorkerThread` and `ThreadPool` to implement concurrency as exemplified [here](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/telebot/util.py)

Comment: Update: it has 100% to do with multithreading, because when i tell the framework to only use one thread, the logging messages appear

Answer (score 0):

You have to show more code. In the code which you have shown, `stream_handler` is created, but then `handler` is used in `addHandler`.

My guess will be that your logging level is improperly set causing all the logs from the `WorkingThread1` to be not logged.

Comment: sorry, i have corrected the code. `stream_handler` is in fact used. see update